# How to run Tomcat in a most secure way?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat

We are using Apache Tomcat 7 for my web applications and we have decided to go on production stage.
So now is the time to think about how to secure the Tomcat and the machine. After reading "Apache tomcat security considerations" we decided to go on run tomcat process on dedicated user with minimum scenario. 
From what I understand the best option is to configure it in a way that the running tomcat process has only read privilege to all the tomcat files.

I figured I would do it in this way:

I would create 2 users:

-`tomcat_process` - only for running tomcat

-`admin` - this is the one all the files belong to

`tomcat_process` will have access to `conf` directory, and also will be able to run scripts from tomcat/bin/

My main problem is that Tomcat needs to write to some files in $CATALINA_HOME/$CATALINA_BASE. I know I can change the location of `logs` and `work`  directory and I thought I would point them to `tomcat_process` home dir (is this even a good idea?). 
But I can't find any information if I can change the path to  `/conf/Catalina` dir. Is it possible?
I would like to avoid adding write access to conf directory, as the whole configurations sits in there.

Or do you think that I should live those directories where their are and just add write privileges to them for `tomcat_process`?
I was wondering if you could please tell me if this is a correct approach or can I do it better?

I'm so confused with all those security guides which are telling me to restrict privileges but not telling how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple I think is the key:

1. Create a new tomcat for each (set of) web application(s) with their own user.
2. Limit the tomcat resources to only the tomcat user. In linux you can use the chmod/chown command  for this.
3. Place the tomcat behind a reverse proxy: Internet (https) <- external Firewall -> Apache Reverse Proxy <- Internal Firewall (block all unless whitelisted) --> Tomcat
4. Delete all standard webapps 'manager', 'root', 'docs'
5. Disable the shutdown command in server.xml
6. As for java web applications try to contain them in their own sandbox, meaning own database, own users.

To safe maintenance effort, you could run multiple instances using one tomcat binary and a single tomcat user.
http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188102/How-to-Run-Multiple-Instances-of-Tomcat-on-a-Single-Server